# how can i know if calloc fails to initialize

Tags: c, calloc

I have read that calloc (malloc+init) will sometimes fail to init array with zero bytes (but will still return pointer to a malloc'ed array). but in [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/) it does not specify that it will return NULL, is there a way to be sure that array was initialized to zero (better then going over array), if not what is the advantage of calloc over malloc ?

Comment: Neither the [Linux manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc), the [MSDN manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f8w183e(v=vs.100).aspx) or the [POSIX manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/calloc.html) mentions this condition. Where did you read about it failing setting the memory?

Comment: _" If the function failed to **allocate** the requested block of memory, a NULL pointer is returned. "_ **allocate** not **init** http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/

Comment: @samray: The C standard is quite consistent about this, if it doesn't describe a library function failing (in a particular way), then it cannot fail (in that way). So you might as well ask what happens when `memset` fails, as ask what happens when `calloc` fails to clear the memory. The answer to both is the same -- it is not permitted to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `calloc()` returns a non-NULL pointer, the block of memory will be zero'ed.

Unless you have a buggy library. In which case you should tread carefully. And maybe consider getting a new toolchain, fix the bug (most libraries come with source) or write your own version of `calloc()` on top of `malloc()` or something.

I think that chances are that `calloc()` is going to be rock solid, unless you have an absolutely ancient, pre-standard compiler or maybe some compiler that's targeting very, very small systems where they felt the need to cut corners (which I'd assume they will have documented).

Comment: thanks, documentation needs to add this, it is written there : " _If the function failed to **allocate** the requested block of memory, a NULL pointer is returned._ " - failed to **allocate** not failed to **initialize**.

Comment: Well, if it succeeded in allocating it, then initializing is implied to have succeeded. If you can't initialize (i.e. write) to a block of memory you seemingly have been allocated, you have bigger issues.