# calloc() usage and checking for failure in C

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, calloc

G'day!

Usually if I was using malloc, I'd check for failure via:

```
int *A;

A=(int *)malloc(NUM_ELEMENTS*sizeof(int));
if (!A) {
    printf("mem failure, exiting \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Can I do the same thing for calloc, even though everything is assigned to 0? My gut feel is yes, because we'd be checking the mem address of A, and it doesn't matter that A[0] is 0, the mem address won't be null unless it failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can error check `calloc` just like `malloc`.  However, since `calloc` is fairly rock-solid failure wise, you usually don't need to do so, as explained here [how can i know if calloc fails to initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289940/how-can-i-know-if-calloc-fails-to-initialize).

Comment: Including a check can still catch errors such as trying to allocate more memory than is available.  I got caught out by running `calloc(big_calculated_number)` on a 32-bit architecture; checking whether calloc succeeded would have saved me a day's bug hunting!

Answer (score 2):

Yes your thinking is correct.  You can do the same check with `calloc` for the reasons you stated.

Answer (score 2):

OP's code works as well with `malloc()` as `calloc()`.

But OP is incorrect with "mem address won't be null unless it failed."

If the requested allocation size is 0, the returned pointer *may* be `NULL`.

> "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object." C11dr §7.22.3.1 1

A more portable solution:

```
A = calloc(NUM_ELEMENTS, sizeof *A);
A = malloc(NUM_ELEMENTS * sizeof *A);

// Add size check
if (!A && NUM_ELEMENTS != 0) {
   fputs("mem failure, exiting \n", stderr);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Of course if `NUM_ELEMENTS` is always > 0, then this additional check is not needed.